# Display a list of twitter accounts with twitter controls/info

Tags: twitter

I have some lists of twitter accounts that I would like to recommend on my website (e.g. follow these great crafting bloggers). If I have the twitter ID for each of these people, is it possible to create a list of items that show their twitter info (pic, number of tweets/followers, etc.) as well as controls that allow the user to follow each (or multiple) twitter account? I'd like to be able to do it dynamically based on the list of accounts so that I can update the list and not have to redesign the page. I feel like I've seen this around the web before, but I don't see any widgets for doing it and I'm wondering how it's done.

(I would like to use javascript/jquery, but am pretty flexible here)

Thanks!
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

I would first look at the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/).  You will find more information on how Twitter works, and you may find information applicable to what you want to accomplish on your website. It's a start, and there's no better place to start than the source itself.

Comment: Thanks! Just started digging into it today. Thought I'd at least make sure I wasn't about to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: "I feel like I've seen this around the web before..." <-- I'm sure you have ;)